Why does the MySQL optimizer estimate results for unmatched criteria in execution plans?
Take a look at the below Query:
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID 
FROM Customers JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
WHERE Customers.CustomerID < -1 
AND Orders.OrderDate > '2024-05-10' 
AND Products.Price > 100 
AND OrderDetails.Quantity >1 
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerID;

Optimizer Trace:
"considered_execution_plans": [
              {
                "plan_prefix": [
                ],
                "table": "`customers`",
                "best_access_path": {
                  "considered_access_paths": [
                    {
                      "access_type": "ref",
                      "index": "PRIMARY",
                      "usable": false,
                      "chosen": false
                    },
                    {
                      "rows_to_scan": 10,
                      "filtering_effect": [
                      ],
                      "final_filtering_effect": 0.1,
                      "access_type": "scan",
                      "resulting_rows": 1,
                      "cost": 1.25,
                      "chosen": true,
                      "use_tmp_table": true
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "condition_filtering_pct": 100,
                "rows_for_plan": 1,
                "cost_for_plan": 1.25,
                "rest_of_plan": [ .... ]
    }
]

MySQL Optimizer checks all the combinations for finding the best plan here. From which I have included only the plans that starts with Customer table.  When it starts with Customer table, the criteria (Customers.CustomerID < -1) would eliminate all the rows(no matching rows are there), then why it takes resulting_rows as 1 and why is the final_filtering_effect = 0.1? Is it because there might be a chance that statistics was not updated and the Optimizer assumes that there can be a row in Customer table satisfying this criteria?
